# Cannot trigger WebMethod (.Net 2.0 aspx)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm Trying to call a function in the code behind an aspx page and getting nowhere with it.  I've always used generic handlers (ashx files) but wanted to put some web methods in a page itself instead.  I've gone right back to basics and created a new application with 1 page and simply added a button, a script reference (jQuery) and a script.  There's 1 web method that simply returns a string.  Here's the code...

**aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebMethod.aspx.cs" Inherits="temp_WebMethod" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <button id="hello" type="button">Say Hello</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#hello").on("click", function () {

            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {},
                dataType: "JSON",
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebMethod.aspx/Hello"
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                console.dir(error);
                alert(textStatus);
            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class temp_WebMethod : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=false)]
    public static string Hello()
    {
        return "{\"response\":\"Hello world\"}";
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty basic and I just want to get the concept working before I start trying to use it.

At the moment, I get the page returned to the ajax call, as if there's no method name at the end of the url.  Also, if I put a breakpoint in the `Hello()` method then it's never triggered.  I have looked at LOTS of websites (and plenty of questions here) and none of them have helped in the slightest.

I'm properly at a loss as to why I can't get such a simple thing to work and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is `WebMethod.aspx` in the root directory?

Comment: No, it's not.  It's in a subfolder of a website that the code will eventually be used on.

Comment: What if you put `alert('test');` before the ajax call? Do you see the alert?

Comment: Yes, I can see that the ajax call is correctly being triggered, executed and returning.  The problem is the the web method is never being called.

Comment: Try to use firebug and see if there's any errors.

Comment: There are no client-side errors.  The page is getting returned to the ajax call, as if the web method is not appended to the URL.

Comment: That's weird, I just tested myself with Visual Studio 2010 Express and it worked. Which Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2010, not express, but it should be the same.  That is weird.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add following code into web.config file.....

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: It's not cross-domain, and even if it were I wouldn't get the web page as a response ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would try it as a GET, then you can hit it in the browser and see exactly what text comes out.  Once you have an ajax request working with the GET, change it to a post and change your javascript as well.